# Is it possible to have more than one server hosting the same Tor Hidden Service?

Tags: onion-services

If I ran a Tor Hidden Service on a server, would it be possible to mirror it on one or more other servers, and use the same onion-address for all?  I was thinking having the mirror(s) periodically checking the main server, and then start-up it's own Tor-service and http-daemon if it couldn't connect to the main-server for several tries.

What I'm really asking, is if it's possible to have several servers reveiling hidden services with *exactly* the same onion-address?

If it's possible, what would I have to copy from the main-server to the mirrors?  Some config-file for Tor?  The main-servers host-keys?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done, you need the domain file,and the key file to enable Tor to start the service with the correct onion domain, you also have to set up your hidden service in the torrc file (copy\paste it, or copy the file).

But keep in mind things can stop for a bit if one goes down and the other is starting up, also running both at the same time can cause issues, so make sure your just run one at a time.

Comment: As I understand that, this was the point of OPs questions, if it would make troubles, when there are two servers with the same key running simultaneously.